# Israel - Identification of Stone statue

Tags: identify-this, israel

I recently read a book about Israel titled "[Israel, Enchantment of the World](http://scholasticlibrary.digital.scholastic.com/subject/social-studies/enchantment-of-the-world/978-0-531-25313-7.html)".

It features a cover that has a stone wall in the background and what seems to be a tall stone statue with a long carved face.

However, in the book there's no mention of this, and I don't know what it is. I've asked some local Israelis what it is, but they didn't know.

So, **what and where is this**:

[image]

Comment: I think if you look in the front cover, or the first few pages of the book, it'll say what the cover picture is of. It should be near the copyright information.

Comment: If it isn't ID'd as described above, you might try your question over in History.SE, with the archaeology & israel tags: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology

Comment: @MichaelC. I borrowed the book from a library, and did go through the content on the first page (where all of the copyright, publishing etc. info is); I didn't find a mention of it, although I can check again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The photo was [taken by photographer Jean Du Boisberranger](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/israel-neguev-desert-sculpture-near-ramon-high-res-stock-photography/75292606) and is titled "**Israel, Neguev desert, sculpture near Ramon crater**". Searching a bit further shows that this is a sculpture from "[Mitzpe Ramon Desert Sculpture Park](http://www.timesofisrael.com/seven-of-the-jnfs-best/)":

> Winter is the perfect time for a trip to Mitzpe Ramon. One favorite
>   attraction is the JNF’s extraordinary Desert Sculpture Park, which
>   runs for two kilometers along the edge of the Ramon Crater. It was
>   born in 1963 when artists from all over the world were invited to
>   create whatever took their fancy. All of them – from Cuban artist to
>   Japanese sculptor – chiseled works out of one large rock. When
>   environmentalism became popular in the ’80s, Israeli sculptors added
>   works of their own.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you were able to locate this on Getty Images?

Comment: @CJBS Tineye search of the book's cover

Comment: Interesting. I've done that before with Google Images reverse image search, but it only came up with other images of the book cover. TinEye gives the Getty Image at the end - so the algorithm's better. Great resource - thanks. https://www.tineye.com/search/f8756ef3af49e496a9e63582e10e4a706ef14e0b/